# dojox.mobile.ScreenSizeAware How to check whether currently in tablet or phone mode?

Tags: html, dojo, dojox.mobile

I am using dojox.mobile.ScreenSizeAware for tablet/phone orientation.

I want to disable some buttons in my app when ScreenSizeAware is in tablet mode.

I checked the documentation and there is a method isPhone() for identifying current display mode. However, I could not figure out how to call this method.

Here is how my related HTML tags are:

```
<span data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware" id="sszaware"></span>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter" data-dojo-props='orientation:"H"' id="mainSplitter">
```

I tried following javascript code but it says object / HTMLDivElement has no method isPhone:

```
alert(digit.byId('sszaware').isPhone()); //error
alert(digit.byId('mainSplitter').isPhone()); //error
alert(dojo.byId('sszaware').isPhone()); //error
alert(dojo.byId('mainSplitter').isPhone()); //error
```

I also tried the following and even that gives an error:

```
require(["dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware"], function(sSzAw){
    alert(sSzAw.isPhone()); //error
});
```

I have already subscribed to following topics to trigger my code when the mode changes. However these topics/events are triggered only when the display mode changes from phone to tablet or vice versa. They do not trigger at the beginning when the webpage just loads in browser.

```
require(["dojo"], function(dojo){
    dojo.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/screenSize/tablet", function(dim){ //this works fine when orientation changes from phone to tablet mode
    alert("Reorienting tablet");
    showButtons(false);
});

dojo.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/screenSize/phone", function(dim){ //this works fine when orientation changes from tablet to phone mode
    alert("Reorienting phone");
    showButtons(true);
});
});
```

I did a lot of searching but couldn't find an example on programmatic usage of ScreenSizeAware. Eventually I am coming door to the experts on stackoverflow to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dijit.byId` in stead of `dijit/byId`. And if you're using AMD syntax, it should be

```js
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
    console.log(registry.byId("sszaware").isPhone());
});
```

But keep in thoughts that the `dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware` module is reported as being **experimental**. The API might change drastically when you change versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dimitri. Actually I had typos in my question above. I was using `dijit` in my code and not `digit`. I tried your recommendation and still getting the followinng error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isPhone' of undefined`. I tried putting  `sszaware` id in both the HTML tags i mentioned in my question (one at a time) but it does not work on either of them. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to call isPhone method on a ScreenSizeAware instance not on the class as you are doing here.

Comment: Hi Chris, how do I get reference to the ScreenSizeAware instance that I already have created through HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware"], function(ready, ssa) {
    ready(function(){
        console.log("isPhone: " + ssa.getInstance().isPhone());
    });
});
```

(for an example, see dojox/mobile/tests/test_ScreenSizeAware-demo-tag.html).

Comment: OK, this seems to be working fine from the perspective of being able to access `isPhone()` method. However, `isPhone()` always returns `false` regardless of `ScreenSizeAware` is in phone mode or tablet mode. Hence, my problem is not solved yet :(

Comment: I realized that `ssa.getInstance()` is creating a brand new instance of `ScreenSizeAware` and not really getting me a reference to the existing instance. That's why `isPhone()` is always returning false. I need to find out how I can get reference to existing `ScreenSizeAware` instance that is being created declartively through HTML tags I listed in the original question

Comment: I was able to resolve this. The problem was because I was including a separate span tag for ScreenSizeAware. Instead of keeping this separate tag, once I added `ScreenSizeAware=true`on the fixed splitter tag, I was able to get a reference to the object with `ssa=ScreenSizeAware.getInstance()`